# Copying to a FAT16 storage device on Windows 7 (x64)

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, fat16

I recently configured an ARM development board (LPC2148) using a bootloader ([this one](http://ics.nxp.com/support/documents/microcontrollers/zip/boot.loader.lpc2132.lpc2134.lpc2136.lpc2138.lpc2142.lpc2144.lpc2146.lpc2148.zip)) so that my laptop recognizes it as a USB mass storage device and I can drag-and-drop the binary files directly into its ROM. 
The PC recognizes it as a FAT16 device and I am am unable to copy any files into it (although I am able to view the drive and the files in it) when on Win7 (64-bit) but it works fine in my old 32-bit WinXP.
Is there any way to add the same functionality to Win7 (maybe through virtual machines running XP). I am using the Home Premium version, so I can't run the XP Mode.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a "real" solution to your problem, but it works for me:

I created a Windows XP Virtual Machine with VMware Player (should also work with the Microsoft Windows XP mode which is actually a Microsoft Virtual PC). I created a network share on my development folder and accessed it from within the virtual machine.

The USB storage can be bound to the virtual machine, so that there is a quite direct access to it. I now move the files from the networt share to the USB mass storage. It works quite nice and the overhead is not that bad. I'm also using this solution for working with my IC programmer which is 10 years old and not in any way supported by Windows 7.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry for the late follow-up on this post. Thanks for the useful suggestion. I tried running XP as a virtual machine on the Win7 host but to no avail. The OS recognizes the USB drive but is unable to copy the files onto it, the OS just 'hangs' - although the "real" WinXP did copy the said files successfully. Any clue what I might be messing up? Thanks again.